# Typescript decorator and this context

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-decorator

I am using decorators in typescript/angular in the following way

```
export function Field({source}){
  return (target, property) => {
    // Some code here
  }
}
```

Then I want to use it this way

```
 export class MyClass {

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  @Field({source: () => this.myFn()})
  myProp: string;

  private myFn() { 
   // another code 
   return this.myService.get()
  }
}
```

Obviously the context is wrong and "this" does not refer to the instance of MyClass.
What is the best way to link this context with the instance of MyClass?

Comment: I don't think you can modify things at the instance level, but you should be able to do it at the prototype level, that is, the decorator could turn that prop into a getter on the prototype `@Field({source: MyClass.prototype.myFn)` or `@Field({source: 'myFn')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to instances in decorators with roundabout methods depending on what you're trying to do.  In the example below the function passed to the decorator is called every time the property is set.

The decorator will work for both properties and fields.  If a field is being decorated then the prototype of the target is modified and the field is converted into a property with a hidden backing variable to store the property value.

Note how this does not use arrow functions to define the getter and setter.  This is how it the instance can be retrieve at the time the property/field is getting set.  Personally, I use arrow functions so much I forget something like this was even possible until I tried it out.

```
function Field(srcFunc) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor?: PropertyDescriptor) {
    if (descriptor == null) {
      const backingKey = `__${propertyKey}`;
      Object.defineProperty(target, backingKey, { enumerable: false, writable: true });
      Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        get: function() {
          return this[backingKey];
        },
        set: function(value) {
          this[backingKey] = value;
          srcFunc.call(this);
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      const setOriginal = descriptor.set;
      descriptor.set = function(value) {
        setOriginal.call(this, value);
        srcFunc.call(this);
      }
    }
  }
}

export class MyClass {

  @Field(MyClass.prototype.myFn)
  myProp: string;

  private myFn() { 
   // another code 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work. However, it does not alter this context and will not work in more specific case. I updated my question to describe what is the issue. Even if I put @Field({source: MyClass.prototype.myFn}), inside myFn method "this" is still not set.

Comment: I wish I knew the specific case.  But there is no way I know of to get the context in the decorator factory function directly, so whatever I come up with will be somewhat of a rig.